# SIGTERM signal not caught when the last process is tail

Tags: linux, bash, signals

I have the following script, which has `tail --pid=${somepid} -f ${mylogs}`. I want to catch `SIGTERM` and do some graceful shutdown on that PID, because that process does not understand `SIGTERM` and dies painfully.

```
echo "pid: $$"

trap_with_arg() {
    func="$1" ; shift
    for sig ; do
        trap "$func $sig" "$sig"
    done
}

func_trap() {
    echo Trapped: $1
}

trap_with_arg func_trap INT TERM EXIT STOP
tail -f /dev/null
```

When I use `kill -15 ${bashpid}` from another terminal, the trapped signal is not printed until I use CTRL+C. When the last command is not a process, but rather a `read` which is a shell built-in, the trapped signals are printed immediately. Why is this the case? If I do the following it works:

```
tail -f /dev/null &
wait $!
```

Comment: So you basically want to `tail` the logs until the PID is alive?

Comment: It already does that, but it process can change, and I want the script to run forever until SIGTERM is received, the problem happens when the tail is running in foreground

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a look at [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes. When bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the `wait` builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the wait builtin to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.